# Extra character 'j:' in cookie set via ExpressJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, cookies

I'm setting a cookie in ExpressJS like so:

```
var content = {id: 'FAC0004',name: 'New York, USA',result: true};
res.cookie('COOK', content);
```

I am able to correctly read the values using `req.cookies.COOK.name` in ExpressJS. But if I try to read the same value using AngularJS like:

```
console.log($cookies.get('COOK'))
```

...I get the result like this: `j:{"id":"FAC0004","name":"New York, USA","result":true}`

Why is there a `j:` in the front?

Comment: Although it's a duplicate, the answer doesn't give a reason why. 

`Hi! It's not part of any standard, as the RFC for cookies says the value can only be a string. Ideally if we followed the standard, we would reject your cookie if it wasn't a string. As a convenience, Express.js allows you to set non-strings as the values, and we'll JSON.stringify the value, pre-pending a j: so we know the value should be JSON.parsed when we read it again for you` - Doug Wilson https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2815

Comment: @Doug Wilson: I wanted to ask this but I dozed off. Thanks for mentioning it here. Should I reopen the question so you can add it as an answer?

Comment: Don't think that is necessary, I added it to the duplicate answer.

Comment: @Jordonias: Thanks! :)